# Wagtail/Django block doesn't render content properly from custom/nested StructBlock template

Tags: python, css, django, templates, wagtail

I have a block in the head of my base template that will render "extra" CSS. This CSS will be customized from fields coming in from a Wagtail CMS instance.

So, in the `base.html` template I have:

```
<head>
  {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Then, in my `detail.html` template, which extends off of the base, I have:

```
{% block content %}
  {% for block in page.body %}
    {{ block }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`body` is a `StreamField` in Wagtail. One of said fields is a custom `StructBlock`, the model of which is set up like so:

```
class CalloutBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    accent_color = blocks.CharBlock(required=False, label='Accent Color', help_text='HEX Value/Color')
    class Meta:
        template = 'inc/blocks/callout.inc.tpl'
```

Finally, in that `callout.inc.tpl` template, I am attempting to render a `<style>` tag that *should* get injected in my `extra_css` block:

```
{% block extra_css %}
  <style>
    .accent_color {
      background-color: {{accent_color}} !important;
    }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

However, this block is not injected into the `<head>` as I'd expected. Instead, it renders in the body, like so, as if the `{% block extra_css %}` tag were not there at all:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .accent_color {
      background-color: {{accent_color}} !important;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Is simply a limitation in Django templates? Is nesting the issue? Or is it because I'm using a custom template at the model level, and that's somehow outside the scope of the parent template parsing?

Django: 1.10
Wagtail: 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation in the way custom templates for StreamField blocks work. (There's a similar limitation in Django templating in general too, though - the `{% block %}` mechanism only works in conjunction with `{% extends %}`, not `{% include %}`.) The HTML content for the block is rendered in a separate call to the template engine, independently of the outer page template, so there's no way of passing control between the two.

(Note that Wagtail 1.6 introduces the [`{% include_block %}`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/1.6.html?#include-block-tag-for-improved-streamfield-template-inclusion) tag, which improves the situation a bit by making it possible to pass variables from the outer template's context to the block template. It still won't allow passing control from one to the other, though.)